# Why two objects created in same line are having same objects but this is not same with lists?

Tags: python, python-internals

In below code a and b are having same ids

```
>>> a,b=470,470
>>> id(a)
32404032
>>> id(b)
32404032
```

but not here,

```
>>> a = 470
>>> b = 470
>>> id(a)
32403864
>>> id(b)
32344636
```

And also if same list objects are created in same line then giving different ids

```
>>> a,b=[1,2], [1,2]
>>> id(a)
32086056
>>> id(b)
32653960
>>>
```

Why variables with same integers created on same line have same ids but not when created on different lines, this is also different with lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for **immutable** objects the compiler will create *constants* and re-use them. You can't do this for mutable objects like lists however, because then you'd be manipulating *the same object* if you made changes via one reference or another.

You can extract the constants by looking at the `co_consts` attribute of a code object; the easiest way to get one of those is to use the `compile()` function:

```
>>> compile("a,b=470,470", '', 'single').co_consts
(470, None, (470, 470))
```

In the interactive interpreter, separate lines are compiled separately, so have *separate constants*. In a separate Python script, each scope has their own constants allowing for wider sharing. In the interactive interpreter, create a function or class to get a separate scope with their own constants:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 470
...     b = 470
...     return id(a) == id(b)
...
>>> foo()
True
>>> foo_code = compile('''\
... def foo():
...     a = 470
...     b = 470
...     return id(a) == id(b)
... ''', '', 'single')
>>> foo_code = compile('''
... def foo():
...     a = 470
...     b = 470
...     return id(a) == id(b)
... ''', '', 'single')
>>> foo_code.co_consts
(<code object foo at 0x1018787b0, file "", line 2>, None)
>>> foo_code.co_consts[0].co_consts  # constants for the foo function code object
(None, 470)
```

These are implementation details (optimisations), you should not rely on them.